# Trying to buy once price closes above previous high

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am new to pine script and am trying to run a strategy that buys when the price closes above the highest high of the last 20 candles.

Here is the part of the code that is giving me issues

```
oldhigh = highest(high, 20)
newhigh = close > oldhigh
plot(highest(high, 20))
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=newhigh and inDateRange, comment="New High")
strategy.close("Buy", when=(close < close[1]), comment="Close")
```

From the strategy tester I can see that it hasn't placed a single order. I assume that it is making a new high as price goes up and is including that into the oldhigh part of the code, making it so the close can never go above the high because it is the new high. With that being said I am lost on how to fix that problem so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct! The trouble lies in that each time we make a new high it pushes the highest line up so we cannot detect a cross. To avoid this we must exempt this high from the calculation by using a historical operator [1].

```
oldhigh = highest(high, 20)
newhigh = close > oldhigh[1]
plot(oldhigh[1])
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=newhigh and inDateRange, comment="New High")
strategy.close("Buy", when=(close < close[1]), comment="Close")
```

This way we see the highest 20 up to now. Another suggestion of something to try in your testing for an exit might be to exit if we make a lower close AND a lower low. Just an idea may or may not work.

Cheers!